# How to add item to top of ScrollView children?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocoscreator

In Cocos Creator I've a `ScrollView` and access its `content` like this:

```
Content: {
    default: null,
    type: cc.Node,
},
```

I want to add a new item on top of the children list, when I do:

```
var item = cc.instantiate(this.itemPrefab);
this.Content.insertBefore(item, this.Content.children[0]);
```

I get an error that object doesn't support property or method `insertBefore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at some of the documentation,

( https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.7/symbols/ccui.ScrollView.html )

( https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.0alpha/symbols/cc.Node.html )

Would I be right in thinking that 'Content' is a ccNode being passed to Scrollview?

The closest methods I could find on ccNode were addChild and reorderChild.
They both support a zOrder method which determines the order in which they are drawn. It seems possible that it might affect its order in its parents array.

(Assuming the other items have a zOrder > 0):

You could try,

```
var item = cc.instantiate(this.itemPrefab);
this.Content.addChild(item, 0);
```

Hopefully it works and you don't have to delete the whole array!

Comment: Hi Felix, sorry for the delay.. Thanks, the trick was in setting `localZOrder` but for some unknown reason `addChild` was always giving the same value for all the children. so before adding, I manually increased `localZOrder` value for previous children.

Comment: Sounds very fiddly, I'm glad to hear that you figured it out. I think I would have given up and switched to another project by now. : )